# CLIPS: Asserting facts of arbitrary length

Tags: assertions

An example fact in my system could be `(trip 4 1330 650 boston chicago ... los_angeles)` with any number of cities tacked on at the end.  I know I can match arbitrary lengths using the multifield wildcard (`$?`), but how can I assert a fact with an arbitrary length?  What I want to do is match to one of the facts in the form above, and then append another city to the end of it.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  You can match 0 or more parts of a fact using `$?`.  To use it in the RHS you can assign it to a variable using `$?variable_name`.

To append another city onto the end, you can match your trip fact with `(trip ?arg1 ?arg2 ?arg3 $?cities)` and assert a new trip fact with the city on the end: `(trip ?arg1 ?arg2 ?arg3 $?cities new_city)`.